Why do people say "I don't count" and not "I am not counted"?
Why in English people say "I don't count", like you count something, instead of "I am not counted"?
"I'm not counted" seems better to me, if I want to say that I'm not included in some category, how do natives think about it?

For the same reason we say "it doesn't compute" instead of "it isn't computed" -- the verb is being used in its intransitive sense. See definition 4 under 'intransitive verb' here: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/count

Can you give a context? If you're literally counting people (eg how many want pizza), then "I don't count" means "don't include me" but "I'm not counted" is ambiguous ("you missed me" or "don't include me"). But if it is with the sense "I'm not important" then "I don't count" sounds more modest and is just more idiomatic. Or there are other contexts.

"I don't count" isn't about enumeration, it's about significance and value. It's definition B2 of "count" from the Cambridge Dictionary:

to have value or importance

For example:

My friends ignored my views on the choice of restaurant. It seems I don't count.


You will occasionally encounter "I am not counted", particularly "I am not counted among their number".
But "I don't count." is a complete thought, while "I am not counted" on its own is not.

"I am not counted" is grammatically fine on its own.

@StuartF, It is grammatical, but it always refers to a specific count; it is not an intrinsic property of the person. We can ask the question "how many people are not counted?" and answer it by counting those who are not in the previous count.
